# Combinations of numbers summing up to 31 with 2 numbers repeating twice

Tags: combinations

I'm wondering how many combinations of number I can get and what they are with the following rules applied:
6 digits of numbers
summing up to 31
2 pairs of the same numbers

Comment: Is there any restriction on the other two numbers? For example, can they be one number that is already repeated? Can they be the same number?

Comment: Nope, they cannot be the same number so there'll be 4 different numbers in total

Comment: When you say digits, do you mean that they are restricted to $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$?

Comment: Yes, only 0-9 :)